# How to get users avatars from different app?

Tags: python, django

I have two apps, reviews & Profiles and I'm looking to make them work together by getting the users profile picture along side the review they leave. However, when I try to access it, it doesn't come up. How can I get the users profile picture and not just their name?

**profile.models**

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.db import models


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, null=True, blank=True)
    picture = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

**business.models**

```
class BusinessReview(models.Model):
    business = models.ForeignKey(Business)
    user_id = models.ForeignKey(User)
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=350)
    recommend = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    rating = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

**/templates/directory/single.html/**

```
{% for review in business.businessreview_set.all %}

  <h4 id="review_title">{{ review.title }}<h4>
  <blockquote>{{ review.description }}</blockquote>
  <h5>{{ review.rating }}</h5>
  <p>{{ review.user }}</p> <!-- replace with profile.user.picture -->
  <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

django will return the url from the ImageField like so:

```
{% for review in business.businessreview_set.all %}

  <h4 id="review_title">{{ review.title }}<h4>
  <blockquote>{{ review.description }}</blockquote>
  <h5>{{ review.rating }}</h5>
  <img src="{{ review.user_id.profile.picture.url }}" />
  <br>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: That is the answer! Thank you so much, but it shouldn't be `{{ review.user_id.picture.url }}`, it should be `{{ review.user_id.profile.picture.url }}`. Can you please amend and I will accept?